# Marginal density function with respect to X and Y in python

Tags: python, math, statistics, probability

I have a joint density function in two variables x and y and I need to calculate marginal density function in X and Y using quad in python for function `f(X, Y) = y*e**(-y(x+1))`

```
from scipy.integrate import dblquad import numpy as np import math

def f(x,y):
    return y*math.exp(-y(x+1)) # Joint Density Function

ans,err = dblquad(f,0,math.inf, lambda x: 0 , lambda x:math.inf)

ans
```

I am trying the above code in Jupyter notebook but for marginal density function, we need only limit for the integral of x and y the above code is throwing an error.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you out

```
from sympy.abc import x,y
from sympy import integrate
fxy = y*e**((-y*x-y))
fy = integrate(fxy,(x,0,ifty))
fx = integrate(fxy,(y,0,ifty))
fy
fx
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo error in your `Joint Density Function` `f` function. You missed one `*` for the product of `-y` and `(x+1)` in `math.exp` function. Fixing that typo error, your program should work.

```
def f(x, y):
    return y*math.exp(-y*(x+1))
```